# "Bop the fizz" - what's the meaning?

Tags: slang, colloquial-language, internet

What is the meaning of "bop the fizz" in this sentence?

*What kind of question is it? "hey who wants to go for lunch?" is a different question from "hey could you bop the fizz for Bigclient?"*

The sentence comes from https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/150798 .

- Am I correct to think it means "do the stuff"?
- Can you use "bop" and "fizz" separately in some contexts where they would keep the meanings "do" and "stuff"? Examples, please.
- How colloquial is this expression, especially comparing to "do the stuff"?
- Is it characteristic only to some specific English-speaking countries?
- Are there any synonyms besides "do" and "stuff" which are at least the same common to hear?

Comment: As a native BrE speaker, I've never heard the phrase *bop the fizz*. Possible they just meant '*something* the *something*'

Answer (score 1):

That was me! They are semi-random placeholder words for arbitrary actions. it is also a vague reference to the games [bop-it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bop_It) and [Fizz Buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz)

It is not an existing saying that is used anywhere on earth as far as I know but you understood my meaning perfectly: do something for this client.